# webform civicrm field Campaign list is not in alphabetical order

Tags: webform-civicrm

I use drupal v7.69 and Civi version 5.35 recently upgraded for a client.
We have a drupal webform with civi donation fields, which has Campaigns as select options.
When i add this field to the webform, it is not in alphabetical order of the campaign titles, instead it is ordered based on the Campaign's Id.
I checked the field's settings in the webform but they are usual.
I can't figure out what would be wrong.

Comment: a workaround could be to set to Static and re-order them manually. not great but maybe not bad if not many campaigns and there are not new ones being added all the time